# Cannot click button using Selenium - Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having issues clicking a button with Selenium. I have never worked with Selenium before, so I have tried searching the web for a solution but have had no luck. I tried some other things such as WebDriverWait but nothing has worked.

```
# My Code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "F:\SeleniumProjects\chromedriver.exe"


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized");
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)
driver.get("https://www.discord.com")

time.sleep(3)
buddy = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/header[1]/nav/div/a")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(buddy).click().perform()
```

This exception is confusing me because I know I can interact with it but I am unsure why it says it isn't. I am sure there is some simple fix but I am stumped.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: https://discord.com/login has no size and location
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)
```

Here is the button I am trying to press

```
<a class="button-195cDm buttonWhite-18r1SC buttonSmall-2bnF7I gtm-click-class-login-button button-1x6X9g mobileAppButton-2dMGaq" href="//discord.com/login">Login</a>
```

Comment: I wonder if the window for your URL isn't showing, since it says `element not interactable: https://discord.com/login has no size and location`, can you try specifying dimensions for the window with something like `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)` ?, after the `driver.get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap a wait around it and the following should work:

```
buddy = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='appButton-2wSXh-']//a[contains(text(),'Login')]")))
buddy.click()
```

There are 2 elements of this on the page:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Login')]
```

That is why we need to go up one more level to the `div` element in the XPath

Import the following at the top of your script if they aren't there already:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

The `ActionChains` is not needed, that is generally used for dropdown menus, things like that.  Also your `XPath` was the full path in the HTML, that is generally not advisable and can be brittle.

Comment: Thanks, I also don't really know how to find the correct XPath in situations like this, is there some sort of tutorial or something I can read up on to have a better understanding on finding these elements properly?

Comment: Here is how I learned..go to whatever website you want in Chrome. Click `F12`, that should open Chrome Dev Tools.  Click dockside bottom.  In the HTML click `ctrl-F`. That opens up a Find window.  Now you can practice searching for CSS Selectors or Xpaths. Once you get used to the HTML hierarchy you will see easy it is to construct your own XPaths.  If you combine that with this site here:  https://www.automatetheplanet.com/most-exhaustive-xpath-locators-cheat-sheet/  you will have a good start on generating your own XPath's.  It took me a little while to get the hang of it, but its way better

Comment: You click the arrow in upper left of Dev Tools to narrow down the button/whatever you want to build an XPath for. In the Find window you will know right away if the XPath you are constructing is valid or not, it tells you if it found a match (or more than 1). It is much better than right clicking and copying the Xpath, the reason being that copies the entire XPath and makes it brittle and possibly more prone to breaking.  Good luck!